# Electron TCP server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, tcp, electron

I'm building and Electron+Angular app and I want to make the "Electron" part also a TCP server, allowing multiple client to connect.

The versions I'm using:

1. Angular CLI: 8.0.6
2. Node: 10.15.3
3. OS: win32 x64
4. Angular: 8.0.3
5. NPM:
   6.4.1

I'm trying to use the "net" package for NodeJS and I'm not an expert. When I try to make the Electron app as a client everything works fine (example code here).

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
    client.connect(2000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
        console.log('Connected');
        client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
    });

    client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Received: ' data);
        client.write('Data received');
    });

    client.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Connection closed');
    });
```

Yet when I try to make it act as a server nothing works, no error messages, no unexpeced behaviors (except the fact that the server is not running).

Example of the server code:

```
var net = require('net');

const server = net.createServer();
server.listen(PORT, HOST);

let sockets = [];

server.on('connection', function(sock) {
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort);
    sockets.push(sock);

    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('DATA from ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' data);
    });

    // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('close', function(data) {
        let index = sockets.findIndex(function(o) {
            return o.remoteAddress === sock.remoteAddress && o.remotePort === sock.remotePort;
        })
        if (index !== -1) {
            sockets.splice(index, 1);
        }
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ' ' + sock.remotePort);
    });
});

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

This is running in the main.js file launched as the Electron main process. Both the main process and the render process (in which Angular is displayed) works properly, but the server is not running.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance...

Comment: What exactly do you observe is happening?  Do you get an error when the client tries to connect?  FYI, you should also have `client.on('error', err => console.log(err));` so you are logging any connection or socket errors.  Should also be logging errors on the server-side too `server.on('error', err => console.log(err));`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @jfriend00! I will try to log the errors... I'm not receiving any log related to connections or anything else, I'm just getting the Electron app working (displaying the Angular web view) without any message related to the server... I'll try to log server errors and let you know!

Comment: Tried... nothing is displayed... On the server side I mean, the client side is made in C++, and it is just an emulator for a software that will run on Arduino. The same code on a traditional node.js application works perfectly. The problem is not on the code, it is somewhere in how Electron manages the server listener process and I can't figure out what it is because I don't get any message... It is like it is not running at all...

Comment: Well, you need to be looking for an error with the client connecting.  That was always the likely place the error is occurring since you don't get any message about an incoming connection on the server.  Perhaps you just have the wrong port.

Comment: The client is implemented in C++ using the class CAsyncSocket. The error I get from the client is Error 10035 and is described as "WSAEWOULDBLOCK A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately". This is not very indicative, considering that the exact same piece of code in nodejs works perfectly and accepts incoming connections. While launched in Electron it doesn't...